# On properties of Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

The time-dependent Schrodinger equation:
$$\left \{-\frac {\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m} + V({\bf x}) \right \} \psi({\bf x}, t) = i \hbar \frac \partial {\partial t} \psi({\bf x}, t)$$

has many properties, including to have the first-order derivative with respect to time. According to my professor, this implies it is enough to know the wave at a specific time, e.g. $\psi({\bf x}, 0)$, in order to know the general form $\psi ({\bf x},t)$ at any time.

Why is that? I mean, I don't see the implication. Why should this hold only if I have a first-order derivative but not higher?

Comment: In my experience, a great way to gain intuition for how differential equations work is to learn a bit about the basic Euler method for numerically solving them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An initial value problem based on a linear PDE which is $n^{th}$ order in time requires the specification of the first $n$ time derivatives at the initial time to obtain a unique solution.

This is morally the same as the ODE case; presumably you are familiar with the fact that a first-order ODE requires one initial condition, a second-order ODE requires two, etc.

Comment: "morally"? What does morality have to do with anyting here?

Comment: @Gert "Morally the same" is here used in a metaphorical sense to mean that it isn't *literally* or *technically* the same as the ODE case, but it is *analogous* to that case and can, in broad strokes, be viewed as the same idea in a different context. See e.g. [this EnglishSE post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331414/can-morally-mean-approximately).